# Double vertical scrolling - client requirement - Searching for a good reason to say no

Tags: scrolling

The thing is my clients asks for a contact list where you have something like this

[image: my friends list]

The first ones are the contacts that already are your friends in the app, the second ones are not your friends yet and you are waiting for them to accept you or not.

So my cliente wants the 3 points (see more) thing, so when you tap them all the names that you are seeing go up and more appear, plus you can scroll that list.
The same for the second list.
So suddenly you got 2 vertical scrolls in basically one list.
I really doubt of the effectiveness of that, but i am a rookie and i ask you for help.
I don't want to be right no matter what, maybe the requirement is good.
But in case it is wrong i want to have a solid reason to say no and propose another approach.
Thank you!

Comment: Just a note, if I understood correctly the scenario, it is not a good idea to use the same names for the two cases in the example.

Comment: @Alvaro what do you mean with the same names? The "see more" label?

Comment: "John Doe" is both an already friend, and a not-friend. It was just a comment so it doesn't bring confusion when reading the question.

Comment: @Alvaro you are totally right, i going to change it right now

Comment: much better with Bill Murray :)

Comment: I recommend you take a look at how Spotify does this in their search field.

Comment: @Alvaro in the app?

Comment: yes, when you search

Answer (score 2):

[image]Use of tabs can also solve this problem. Just like the tabs what facebook had in the message earlier(don't know category exactly, I think categories were Friends, Others).

Comment: could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple scrollbars within the same design element is certainly a non-standard design pattern.

**Accessibility:**

Inline scroll areas can be perplexing - and provide particular problems for accessiblity. Where am I in the list? How do I move from one list to another?

Try prototyping out the client-requested solution - is it keyboard accessible?

**Mobile platforms and invisible content**

Some platforms (looking at you, Macs) helpfully hide those yucky scrollbars until you interact with them. Is it always obvious that your content is scrollable? If you end up with invisible scrollbars, will your users know more content is available?

Here is some reading on the topic that may help you:

- http://webaim.org/techniques/frames/
- https://baymard.com/blog/inline-scroll-areas
- https://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-scrollbars/

Comment: Remember, creating inaccessible web properties can make clients vulnerable to litigation. That can be a powerful inducement to commit to supporting accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the good user interface-related answers you've already received, I'd also approach this from a UX goal perspective. What is the primary purpose of the UX workflow this UI component is a part of?

In this workflow is it more important to see a full list of friends, or to only see "pending" friends? One way to answer this question is to ask which list is the end-user more likely to need on a regular basis to accomplish the task defined in your application. Many times, as designers, we're asked to make things with a duality of purpose or to skip early goal definition steps. In my work that raises small red flags, causes me to stop, and ask leading questions to get closer to the true purpose of what's being designed.

Defining the goals of the page/task can help act as guard rails to keep everyone on the team (including the client/stakeholder) focused on only designing a simple, straightforward solution. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, I live in a constant process of growning within UX, it is passionating!